# How can I store images and strings in the same database table and retrieve them

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a form that accepts texts and images and I want to store the data in the same database table. Below is the declaration for my record but they are all strings so how do i convert the images to strings to add to this list:

```
site_info_record.createSiteInfoRecord(sql_sysaid_id, sql_site_id, sql_link_id, sql_customer_name, sql_site_contact,
            sql_task_type, sql_address, sql_region, sql_phone, sql_fax, sql_mobile, sql_email,
            sql_landlord_name, sql_rent_status, sql_loc_cords, sql_power_status, sql_voltage, sql_aircon, sql_server_room,
            sql_location_idu, sql_earthing, sql_distance_idu, sql_security, sql_ducts, sql_unit, sql_install_type,
            sql_isp, sql_radio_type, sql_isp_type, sql_isp_name, sql_snr_rx, sql_bs, sql_remark);
```

And when i want to retrieve, its also in string format:

```
public String getInfoData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ROW_ID, SYSAID_ID, SITE_ID, LINK_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, SITE_CONTACT, TASK_TYPE, ADDRESS,
            REGION, PHONE, FAX, MOBILE, EMAIL, LANDLORD_NAME, RENT_STATUS, LOCATION, POWER_STATUS, VOLTAGE_MEASUREMENT, AIRCON,
            SERVER_ROOM_STATUS, LOCATION_IDU, EARTHING, DISTANCE_IDU, SECURITY_CABLES, DUCTS, UNIT_TYPE, INST_TYPE,
            HAVE_ISP, RADIO, ISP_TYPE, ISP_NAME, SNR_RX, BS, REMARKS};
```

How do i fix images data in these

Comment: Try this.. 1st convert Image to string and save it to database 
http://javahonk.com/convert-string-to-image-java/

Comment: You should really consider Fedor Kazakov's answer, this approach is not optimal. You should store your images on the SD card, not in a database. Instead, store the url pointing to the image in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This will slow your database and application. Instead of this you can try to save to SDCard and keep URI at the db.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but this application will be synced to a Microsoft server and we will need the actual image so I will be better off if i saved the image rather than the path

Comment: Can you direct me to a tutorial on how to get and store the URI?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy
Two options

```
one:  
byte[] bytes = {...}  
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

or

public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);  
    return imageEncoded;
}
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0,         decodedByte.length); 
}
```

two:
You can use GSON and make an object from all your text and ByteArray and what ever you want and than just do: GSON.toJson();

Answer (score 0):

In a table , you can have many columns . To have text and images in same table you can have different columns for them with following data types :-

Text - VARCHAR

Images - BLOB

Sqlite is having a data type BLOB which can hold objects .

Comment: but how do i create my record in string format and get them back in string format

Comment: Explain me about what you are talking ? You do you want in string .